# Mongoose Model returning empty model for property when it should be null

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

First off, I apologize for the title. It's difficult to accurately sum up the problem I am having in a single sentence.

I am using Mongoose 3.8.11 and in my `User` schema I have a `profile_pic` property defined like so:

```
profile_pic: {
    name: { type: String },
    url: { type: String }
}
```

When I load a `User` with a null `profile_pic` from my database, I assume `user.profile_pic` will be `null`. However, `user.profile_pic` is returning a `User` model with every property set to `undefined`. What's even weirder is that `user._doc.profile_pic` is `null` like I would expect. When the `User` has a `profile_pic` in the database, `user.profile_pic` works properly.

Changing the property in my schema to the following works,

```
profile_pic: Schema.Types.Mixed
```

but I'd rather have the property well-defined.

Any help would be appreciated.